# Objects of type File must support the iteration protocol, and iterates through the lines of the file

Tags: python, class, magic-methods

So, I have a few tasks for creating class in python:

- Can someone give me review of my code.
- I need to use Magic Methods to complete tasks.

Here is my tasks:

1) The class must be initialized in the full path.

such as

```
obj = File('/tmp/file.txt')
```

2) The class must support the write method.

3) Objects of type File must support adding.

4) Objects of type File must support the iteration protocol, and iterates through the lines of the file.

```
for line in File('/tmp/file.txt'):
```

And here I have a problem, as a result I heve an infinite loop.

5) When outputting a file using the print function, it should print its full path, passed at initialization.

Here is my code:

```
import os

class File:

def __init__(self, file_path, content = None):
    self.file_path = file_path
    self.content = content
    try:
        with open(file_path) as file_to:
            self.content = file_to.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File or directory does not exist!\nEnter existing directory")


def write(self, line):
    self.line = line
    with open(self.file_path, 'a+') as file_to:
        file_to.write(self.line)

def __add__(self, obj):
        with open('result.txt', 'a+') as new_file:
            new_file.write(self.content + obj.content)

def __iter__(self):
    return self

def __next__(self):
    self.stop = 0
    with open(self.file_path) as f:
        data = f.readlines()
    if self.stop > len(data):
        raise StopIteration

    self.stop += 1

    return data 

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.file_path}"
```

Comment: General code review of working code belongs on [the Code Review sister site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). For the known problems you need help fixing, please provide the necessary parts of a [MCVE] (including code that exercises the class and the expected inputs and outputs).

Answer (score 0):

> And here I have a problem, as a result I have an infinite loop.

You're re-opening the file and reading it all over every time the next method is called by the *for* on the `File` instance. The successive `next` calls will not end as `__next__` keeps returning the same data.

You can instead return an iterator on the file content directly from `__iter__`:

```
class File:

    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.file_path = file_path
        try:
            with open(file_path) as file_to:
                self.content = file_to.readlines()
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File or directory does not exist!\nEnter existing directory")
            raise

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.content)
```

To make the class instance an iterator, i.e. implement the iterator protocol, you can return self in `__iter__`, and return lines of the file in `__next__`:

```
class File:

     def __init__(self, file_path):
        ...
        self._index = 0 

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
           return self.content[self._index]
        except IndexError:
           raise StopIteration
        self._index += 1
```

Comment: This solution assumes it's intended to be an iterable, but not an iterator (all built-in file-like objects are iterators, with `seek`ing required to reset their position).

Comment: @ShadowRanger That's not what I read from the OP: *Objects of type File must support the iteration protocol, and iterates through the lines of the file.* And BTW, there is no explicit requirement to support seeking and all the fancy stuff file iterators provide.They want to support the iterator protocol, and there they have it.

Comment: I don't know what the OP wants. The wording you quoted is too vague to determine intent. Python has a concept of ["iterator protocol"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) (if that was the intent, you'd want an iterator), it has no "iteration protocol". No, they don't need to provide `seek`, but if it's supposed to be an iterator, then having it be an iterable that hands out independent iterators on each `__iter__` call will make it incorrect (two threads iterating the file will each iterate it independently, rather than splitting the lines).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I take it they meant "iterator protocol". Updated.